# Running "./worldserver" displays "Map file './maps/0004331.map': does not exist!" error

Tags: ubuntu, azerothcore, trinitycore

I'm trying to set up Azeroth core server, but while `./authserver` works without any problem, `./worldserver` returns error:

```
Map file './maps/0004331.map': does not exist!
```

- DataDir is set up.
- I tried reinstalling data files.
- I tried updating AC core.

The expected result was that the `worldserver` would boot without trouble, but it returned this error.

**EDIT:** I had to change "DataDir" also in "worldserver.conf.dist" and it "worked" - it pointed right directory, however it still couldn't detect map files. However after a while with changing DataDir variable inside "worldserver.conf.dist" it started displaying:

```
ERROR: Invalid or missing default configuration file : /home/user/azerothcore-server/etc/worldserver.conf.dist
```

So i'm stuck again, any idea what the heck is going on, or maybe i should just reinstall everything with docker?

**EDIT 2:** Solved problem from latest edit with updating AC, but error `Map file './maps/0004331.map': does not exist!` persists. Running it with sudo returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Also `Using DataDir ./`, which is a default value, even when DataDir is changed.

**EDIT 3:** Okay, now it reads worldserver.conf, i just had to modify permissions of all files using

```
find $HOME/azerothcore-server -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Also had to change permissions of data subfolders manually by doing `chmod 755 (foldername)`. Now `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error appears, no idea what's wrong, but right now this question is solved, i'll open a new one for this.

Comment: Can you post image of your Build folder please. Dunno, what files you have there, but you don't need to change .conf.dist file, you need to edit just .conf files. Will be very helpful to see your folder structure, since only problem for you is the maps are not detected (does not exist)

Comment: https://postimg.cc/yks7XyMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `worldserver.conf` you should set the `DataDir` parameter with the **absolute path** of your data directory.

Example:

```
DataDir = "/home/user/azerothcore-server/data"
```

Also you are **NOT** supposed to edit or delete the `worldserver.conf.dist`

Edit: also make sure that the **permissions** of the data directory are properly set

Comment: `DataDir = "/home/user/azerothcore-server/data"` was there already, i checked that.
 Also, how can i recover `worldserver.conf.dist`

Comment: @Crowfunder you can download it again from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/master/src/server/worldserver/worldserver.conf.dist

Comment: Even after restoring the file it displays `ERROR: Invalid or missing default configuration file : /home/crowfunder/azerothcore-server/etc/worldserver.conf.dist`

Comment: @Crowfunder try to update your core to the latest version

Comment: It helped with `worldserver.conf.dist`, but still the same error `Map file './maps/0004331.map': does not exist!`

Comment: @Crowfunder then maybe the problem is the version of your data files

Comment: I've installed the newest possible downloaded directly from https://mega.nz/#F!Am4DBKCR!o9Qj_xFLfsg4sczqg0xq2A linked in AC wiki.

Comment: It were permissions, now i can access map files.